# Unable to Transmit Data from Arduino Nano to Android app via bluetooth module hc-05

Tags: android, arduino, android-bluetooth

So we're working on Smart shoes for the visually impaired, there is a problem we're facing in transmission of data from arduino to android app. We are using a vibrator motor which is the motorPin in arduino code. 
The bluetooth module is connected properly, the led on it is blinking so I think there's a problem with the android app. 
Below is the arduino nano code and android code! Thanks in advance

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
// defines pins numbers
const int trigPin = 6;
const int echoPin = 7;
const int motorPin = 8;
const int tx = 2;
const int rx = 3;
// defines variables
long duration;
int distance;
SoftwareSerial bluetooth(rx,tx);
void setup() {
    pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
    pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
    pinMode(motorPin, OUTPUT); //Sets the motorPin as an Output
    Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication
    bluetooth.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
    // Clears the trigPin
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
    // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in 
       microseconds
    duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
    // Calculating the distance
    distance= duration*0.034/2;
    // Prints the distance on the Serial Monitor
    Serial.print("Distance: ");
    Serial.println(distance);

if (distance < 30)
{
    digitalWrite(motorPin, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    bluetooth.print("1");
    delay(1000);
}
else
{
    digitalWrite(motorPin, LOW);
    delay(1000);
}
}
```

Here is the android code: MainActivity.java

```
 package com.example.shreyagaddam.asfb;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.shreyagaddam.asfb.R;

import java.io.InputStream;
//import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    Button open, close;
    TextView out;
    EditText input;


    BluetoothAdapter ba;
    BluetoothDevice bd;
    BluetoothSocket bs;

    InputStream is;


    Thread workerThread;
    byte[] readBuffer;
    int readBufferPosition;

    volatile boolean stopWorker;

    String speechdata = "";
    TextToSpeech tts;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        out = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data);
        open = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openBT);
        close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.closeBT);


        open.setOnClickListener(this);
        close.setOnClickListener(this);


        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.openBT) {
            try {
                findBT();
                openBT();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.closeBT) {
            try {
                closeBT();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        } else {
            try {
                String data = input.getText().toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    void findBT() throws Exception {

        ba = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (!ba.isEnabled()) {
            Intent i1 = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivity(i1);

        }
        if (ba.isEnabled()) {
            Set<BluetoothDevice> paired = ba.getBondedDevices();
            if (paired.size() > 0) {
                for (BluetoothDevice dev : paired) {
                    if (dev.getName().equals("HC-05")) {

                        bd = dev;

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }

    void openBT() throws Exception {
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("1101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
        bs = bd.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
        bs.connect();

        is = bs.getInputStream();
        recieve();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Socket Opened", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    void recieve() throws Exception {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final byte delimiter = 32;


        stopWorker = false;
        readBufferPosition = 0;
        readBuffer = new byte[1024];
        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker) {
                    try {
                        int bytesAvailable = is.available();
                        if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            is.read(packetBytes);



                                for (int i = 0; i < bytesAvailable; i++) {
                                    byte b = packetBytes[i];
                                    if (b == delimiter) {
                                        byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
                                        System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
                                        final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
                                        readBufferPosition = 0;


                                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                            public void run() {
                                                out.setText(data);
                                                if (data.equals("1")) {
                                                    speechdata = "Obstacle";

                                                    speak();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                     catch (Exception ex) {
                        stopWorker = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        workerThread.start();


    }

    void callme() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            speechdata = "";
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Opps! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                    ArrayList<String> text = data
                            .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

                    speechdata = text.get(0);

                    Toast.makeText(this, speechdata, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (speechdata.contains("restaurant")) {

                        Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=restaurants");
                        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                        startActivity(mapIntent);
                    } else if (speechdata.contains("college")) {
                        Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Sreenidhi+Institute+of+Science+&+Technology,+Hyderabad+India");
                        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                        startActivity(mapIntent);


                    } else if (speechdata.contains("cafeteria")) {
                        Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=SNIST+Cafeteria,+Hyderabad");
                        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                        startActivity(mapIntent);


                    } else if (speechdata.contains("canteen")) {
                        Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=SNIST+College+Canteen,+Hyderbad");
                        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                        startActivity(mapIntent);


                    } else if (speechdata.contains("Block 2")) {
                        Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Departments+of+Computer+science+&+Mechanical,+Hyderabad");
                        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                        startActivity(mapIntent);


                    } else if (speechdata.contains("arts club")) {
                        Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=SNIST+Arts+Club,+Hyderbad");
                        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                        startActivity(mapIntent);


                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {

            callme();
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
            try {
                findBT();
                openBT();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }


        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    void closeBT() throws Exception {
        stopWorker = true;
        is.close();
        bs.close();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Socket closed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            // tts.setPitch(5); // set pitch level

            // tts.setSpeechRate(2); // set speech speed rate

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "Language is not supported");
            } else {

                speak();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
        }

    }

    void speak() {


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            tts.speak(speechdata, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Also, result of `is.read(packetBytes)` in the `void recieve()` function is showing a warning saying that **Result of InputStream.read() is ignored**

Comment: Did you try with any other bluetooth terminal applications available in play store? First make sure the hardware setup is working with the bluetooth terminal application. I don't know about android programming, so I couldn't understand what you doing. HC-05 will support SPP profile(Virtual Serial cable) only, so you have to access the data though SPP profile(or RFCOMM channel corresponding to SPP connection) in android. Are you doing the same? I think there is one example source code for bluetooth chat application available for android. You can refer that and see if you are missing anything.